# Navigating SQL Injection Safeguards

Tags: sql-injection, dvwa

I'm trying to get around the DVWA high security SQL injection challenge, I've tried a bunch of automated scanning tools with no luck, read a bunch of articles saying it's impossible now i've turned to the source code:

You can submit a number (id) to select some details from within the database. I'm trying to pull all rows out:

```
$id = stripslashes($id);
$id = mysql_real_escapse_string($id);

if (is_numeric($id))
{
    SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '$id';
}
```

I've tried putting hex numbers and commands and things through it, it gets past the checks but doesn't work. Now i'm not 100% sure about the backend, but is there anyway to reconstruct the strings from hex once i'm past the `is_numeric()` check?

Dvwa uses mysql_query, not mysqli or prepared statements if that's any help

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: This seems to boil down to: "how can I perform SQLi using only numeric data"?

Comment: hmf, don't suppose you have some magic way of performing sql injection with numeric data? :3

Comment: Care to add the code for mysql_real_escape_String() if it's not too large of a function?

Comment: @KDEx - It can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php